# Using DI to inject ASP.NET Identity using Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, asp.net-identity-2

What I wanted to do is to prevent multiple login in ASP.NET.
And I followed this article: [Prevent Multiple Login in ASP.NET](http://tech.trailmax.info/2015/09/prevent-multiple-logins-in-asp-net-identity/)

After that I followed this article: [Changing PK data type](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/08/cookieauthenticationprovider-and-user-session-invalidation-on-change-of-securitystamp/) to change the data type of primary key from string(default) to long. But I still can't prevent multiple login.

I found out that the reason why it's not working is because I can't get an instance of UserManager

`app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<UserManager>());`

The code above is not working. I'm getting error of

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

After that I found this article: [AspNet Identity and IoC Container Registration](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/) and tried to understand the code but it's using unity. But there is a link above of that article that is using Castle Windsor: [Castle Windsor](https://github.com/andrew-kuzovov/ASPNETIdentityWithCastleWindsor/blob/master/Startup.cs) and I don't know what where does this comes from:

```
var container = DIContainer.GetConfiguredContainer();
```

**UPDATE**
Now I realize that the reason that I can't get the instance of the object is because I can't inject UserManager in StartUp.cs like other .cs files.
For example:

```
private readonly UserManager _userManager;

public StartUp(UserManager userManager)
{
      _userManager = userManager;
}
```

And the code above give me this error:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Please help me !!! It stuck me for few weeks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is fixed. Please go to the link below to check how is it being fixed.

[Solution](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero/issues/413)

Hope this might help those people who is trying to do prevent multiple login as well.
Feel free to ask me if you have any problem and I will try my best to help.